# Dynamically adding cli commands

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-import, typer

I am just getting started with the library Typer for building CLI's.
There are too many commands in my cli.py and I moved them to a separate folder “commands”, but I cannot figure out how to implement a dynamic loader for these commands in cli.py.

```
my_app/
 __init__.py
 commands/
     __init__.py
     command1.py
     command2.py
 cli.py
```

I started by creating a class "Command"  for each command from module "commands" with a single function "handle (** options)"  that contains the functionality. Ideally, when starting cli.py, I want to check which modules are there and load them dynamically, leaving the cli.py file clean. But I do not understand at all how it is better and more correct to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use command groups https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/subcommands/nested-subcommands/

first, you need to create your command like every typer application. for example your commandn.py sould be like below

command.py

```py
import typer

app=typer.Typer()

@app.command()
def test()
   print("Hello")
```

then you can call it into your cli.py

```py
import typer
import commandn

app = typer.Typer()
def main()
    typer.command()(commandn.test)

if _name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```